# How to bind an identifier to a sublist plus delimiter?

Tags: pattern-matching, match, racket, sublist

This `match` binds identifiers `a` and `b` to the prefix `'(0 1)` and the suffix `'(3 4 5)` of the list:

```
(match '(0 1 2 3 4 5)
  [`(,a ... 2 ,b ...)
   (values a b)])
```

Another equivalent version:

```
(match '(0 1 2 3 4 5)
  [`(,@(list a ... 2) ,b ...)
   (values a b)])
```

How to bind an identifier (within the pattern itself) to the prefix `'(0 1 2)`, including the delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app` pattern, which invokes a function with the value being matched and then matches the values it returns, combined with a version of [`splitf-at`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._splitf-at%29%29) that includes the partition element in the first list instead of the second, can be used to do this:

```lisp
; Like splitf-at but includes the element to split at in the first value not the second
(define (splitf-at/inclusive lst pred?)
  (let loop ([lst lst]
             [first-res '()])
    (cond
      ((empty? lst)
       (values (reverse first-res) '()))
      ((pred? (car lst))
       (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) first-res)))
      (else
       (values (reverse (cons (car lst) first-res)) (cdr lst))))))

; Gives '(0 1 2) '(3 4 5)
(match '(0 1 2 3 4 5)
  ((? list? (app (lambda (lst) (splitf-at/inclusive lst (negate (curry = 2)))) a b))
   (values a b)))
```

(Note the use of `(? list? ...)` to make sure the value is a list before trying to call any functions that depend on that.)

You can define a [match extender](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28part._.Extending_match%29) to make it nicer-looking:

```lisp
(define-match-expander split-list
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx (...)
      ((split-list x (... ...) val y (... ...))
       #'(? (lambda (lst) (and (list? lst) (member val lst)))
            (app (lambda (lst) (splitf-at/inclusive lst (lambda (elem) (not (equal? elem val))))) x y))))))

; Also gives '(0 1 2) '(3 4 5)
(match '(0 1 2 3 4 5)
  ((split-list a ... 2 b ...)
   (values a b)))
```

This version also includes a check to make sure the value you want to split on is actually in the list, or it'll fail to match.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn, this is a nice approach, and I will use it.

Comment: A few comments on drawbacks, though: 1) the first "..." in this match expander is not greedy, unlike usual match's ellipsis (that's certainly easy to fix), 2) this syntax is quite rigid in comparison to a list pattern within a match. For example, it would be nice to allow any number of identifiers and also nested list subpatterns, capturing some identifiers within them. This was outside the scope of my question, but calls for a follow-up (using match expanders to transform into a list-clause), I will think about it.